# How to convert list into set in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

```
           date                     uids
0  2018-11-23  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
1  2018-11-24  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

When I use `set` to convert it to set it fails:

```
df['uids'] = set(df['uids'])  # IT FAILS!
```

How should I convert `list` into `set` in place?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use *apply* method of DataFrame API:

```
df['uids'] = df.apply(lambda row: set(row['uids']), axis=1)
```

or

```
df = df['uids'].apply(set) # great thanks to EdChum
```

You can find more information about *apply* method [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

**Examples of use**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[1,2,3,4,5,1,1,1], [2,3,4,2,2,2,3,3]]})
df = df['A'].apply(set)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
0    set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
1          set([2, 3, 4])
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Or:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[1,2,3,4,5,1,1,1], [2,3,4,2,2,2,3,3]]})
>>> df['A'] = df.apply(lambda row: set(row['A']), axis=1)
>>> df
                      A
0  set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
1        set([2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: @EdChum `lambda` solution works great, but maybe your solution doesn't update in place?!

Comment: @AlirezaHos what are you talking about? you can just do `df['usids'] = df['uids'].apply(set)`, there is no `inplace` param for `apply` anyway you have to assign the result

Comment: @EdChum I was just using the part you said. It works now . thanks you! +1

Comment: @EdChum apply function take so long (19 second) as my list includes 30,000 uids. Isn't there a better way to enhance performance?

Comment: `apply` is just a `for` loop so this will be slow unfortunately, there isn't a `toset` method

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who wants to know the fastest way to convert list into set in Pandas:

Method 1:

```
df['uids'] = df.apply(lambda row: set(row['uids']), axis=1)
```

Method 2:

```
df['uids'] = df['uids'].apply(set)
```

Method 3:

```
df['uids'] = df['uids'].map(set)
```

I run timeit with `repeat(50, 5)` on DF with 4000 rows:

```
Method 1 - mean:  0.13299, min:  0.12723
Method 2 - mean:  0.01319, min:  0.01207
Method 3 - mean:  0.01261, min:  0.01164
```