# Conversion of list to sets in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, set

I would like to search for substrings in each row of a dataframe column. I read somewhere that it is faster to search if the column can be converted into a set. I am trying to use the approaches suggested here: [How to convert list into set in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125611/how-to-convert-list-into-set-in-pandas)
But I get some unexpected output. My dataframe looks like this:

```
      R_id        Badges
0    7LBCS        New Reviewer - 1 Review
1    8FKME        New Reviewer - 1 Review; New Photographer - 1 Photo; Reviewer - 3 Reviews;
```

When I use the following approaches:

```
df['Badges'] = df.apply(lambda row: set(row['Badges']), axis=1)
```

OR

```
df['Badges'] = df['Badges'].apply(set)
```

the output that I get for each row in the dataframe above is a set with unique characters of the string in the row. I am not able to replicate the exact output, because for some reason, as soon as the output is generated, the Spyder IDE crashes. But the output for the first row looks something like:

```
{'1', '-', 'N', 'e', 'w', 'R', 'v', 'i', 'r'}
```

What could be going wrong here in the conversion to sets?

Comment: What is the substring you are looking for?

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal For instance, I am looking for "New Reviewer", though for my real purpose I need to search for about 50 different substrings. Some rows contain about 400 descriptors like "New Reviewer", "Reviewer", "New Photographer", etc.

Comment: NIT: Converting to `set` will remove duplicated instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is not in a format that makes it easy to work with. I'd recommend an extension of Andy's code that results in each entry getting its own row, so you can then filter your data much more efficiently.

Start with `str.split`, and then extract key-value pairs using `str.extract`.

```
df = df.set_index('R_id')\
       .Badges.str.split('\s*;\s*', expand=True)\
       .stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=1)\
       .str.extract('(?P<Name>[^-]+).*(?P<Val>\d+)', expand=True)\
       .dropna()

print(df)
                    Name Val
R_id                        
7LBCS      New Reviewer    1
8FKME      New Reviewer    1
8FKME  New Photographer    1
8FKME          Reviewer    3
```

An hour's pain may a century gain.

Comment: Though, I do not fully understand what the code does, after seeing the output I think this suggestion is more helpful to achieve my end goal. But, I have two questions. Can this be done without setting R_id as the index?
That way, I will be able to do some sorting later on using R_id column. Also, the Val field is currently capturing only one digit after the description. In some cases, I have something like, Expert Reviewer - 110 Reviews. How do I alter above code to capture 110 instead of just 1?

Comment: Also, why would I not be able to filter the rows in the new df using the following: df[df.Name=="New Reviewer"]. The command returns an empty dataframe.

Comment: @Rnovice yes and yes. For your first question, call df = df.reset_index(). For the name column, use df.Name = df.Name.str.strip(), I think you have trailing spaces and filtering should work after that.

Answer (score 2):

You have to split before you use set:

```
In [11]: df.Badges.str.split('\s*;\s*').apply(set)
Out[11]:
0                            {New Reviewer - 1 Review}
1    {Reviewer - 3 Reviews, , New Photographer - 1 ...
Name: Badges, dtype: object
```

To throw away the empties I might tweak it as follows:

```
In [12]: df.Badges.str.split('\s*;\s*').apply(lambda bs: set(b for b in bs if b))
Out[12]:
0                            {New Reviewer - 1 Review}
1    {Reviewer - 3 Reviews, New Photographer - 1 Ph...
Name: Badges, dtype: object
```

or you could strip the ';' first (if that's the only place empty comes from):

```
In [13]: df.Badges.str.strip(';').str.split('\s*;\s*').apply(set)
Out[13]:
0                            {New Reviewer - 1 Review}
1    {Reviewer - 3 Reviews, New Photographer - 1 Ph...
Name: Badges, dtype: object
```

*The latter might be slightly more efficient...*