# remove duplicated of numpy array in panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to remove dupicate coordinates. The coordinates are separated in x and y columns.
I have one duplicate in the first cars coordinates (5,7)
I have one duplicate in the second cars coordinates (4,5)

I have this:

```
cars = pd.DataFrame({'x': [[1,2,3,4,5,5,5,7],[4,4,5,6,7,8]],
                     'y': [[3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9],[5,5,6,7,8,9]]})
```

I want this:

```
 cars = pd.DataFrame({'x': [[1,2,3,4,5,5,7],[4,5,6,7,8]],
                      'y': [[3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[5,6,7,8,9]]})
```

I have tried this and it works, only I think it can be solved faster with pandas, any ideas?

```
 for i in range(2):
    k= len(cars['x'][i])
    for j in range(k-2):
        if (cars['x'][i][j] == cars['x'][i][j+1]) & (cars['y'][i][j] == cars['y'][i][j+1]):
            cars['x'][i] = np.delete(cars['x'][i], [j + 1])
            cars['y'][i] = np.delete(cars['y'][i], [j + 1])
            k+=1
print(cars)
```

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125611/how-to-convert-list-into-set-in-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`applymap()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) method:-

```
cars=cars.applymap(lambda x:set(x))
cars=cars.applymap(lambda x:list(x))
```

**Edit:** If you don't want to apply this condition in column z then make use of [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) method:-

```
cars['x']=cars['x'].apply(lambda x:set(x)).apply(lambda x:list(x))
cars['y']=cars['y'].apply(lambda x:set(x)).apply(lambda x:list(x))
```

Comment: Yes, that was faster and shorter! And it took care of my tripplets that I added. Thank you.

Comment: If I have a column z that I do not want to affect, how do i do that?

Comment: Edited my answer...Kindly have a look

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: This takes away the duplicates in x. But I need to delete them only if x,y = x,y.

Comment: what do you mean by x,y=x,y?please tell

Comment: I changes a 6 to a 5 in my question. My data might have diplicates in one row, it is only when x and y are duplicates, as a set, that I need it to be deleted.

Comment: Well sorry to say but I  can't figure out logic regarding this..you should ask another question regarding this

Comment: like in your dataframe let's say at index position 0, x and y aren't duplicates as a set i.e set `x: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7}` set `y:{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}` so how you make change in your resultant dataframe?

Comment: I will ask a new question. Thank you. I think I can use this in an other part of my program.